# Парсинг Date из Mysql в читаемый формат

Tags: дата, php, mysql

Подскажите, как распарсить date (не datetime) из mysql в формат типа "30 января 2015"? Дата получается в формате 2015-01-30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = '2015-01-30';
$locale = 'ru_RU';

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    $locale,
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);
$formattedDate = $formatter->format(new DateTime($date))); // 30 января 2015 г.
```